# Understanding an Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I found this directive for reading a file. It works great, but I would like to understand how it works. Once I have a good understanding, I would like to set an elements background image to the now BASE64 image inside this directive. Any help would be fantastic.

```
.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directive uses the new [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) that is in most modern browsers. This API lets the browser make the file that you choose with an input type=file control available to JavaScript for processing. In short, you initialize the reader, give it a function to run once the file has been loaded, and then tell it to load the file. You can bind this to the input directly with JavaScript, or via a directive like this. The directive calls $scope.$apply because it uses element.bind, which does not link the action to the $scope.